# Angular App with BaseHref not working for css assets URL()

Tags: css, angular

I looked for this issue alot but did not find anything.

Issue :
I am using BaseHref feature of angular as my site needs to be deployed as sub path.
Example :
Main Portal : [www.abv.com](http://www.abv.com)
My angular app url : [www.abv.com/angapp](http://www.abv.com/angapp)

By using BaseHref= '/angapp/', angular redirects all javascripts requests to /angapp/{something.js} urls.
Which is good.

But when it comes to assets, angular/css is trying to fetch from root .
example : I expect an image "logo.png" from [www.abv.com/**angapp**/assets/img/logo.png](http://www.abv.com/**angapp**/assets/img/logo.png)
but app tries to get it from  :[www.abv.com/assets/img/logo.png](http://www.abv.com/assets/img/logo.png)
(basehref value missing)

I looked for the rootcause and its use of
background-image: url(/assets/images/logo.png);
property in css which is not considering baseHref.

Please suggest me if there is any workaround for it ?
Any alternative to URL() ?
Any way to make it go to correct url?

Please reply if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: try `url('./assets/images/logo.png')` or `url('assets/images/logo.png')`

Comment: These two throw build error in ng build

Comment: try with url('../assets/images/logo.png')

Comment: same result : Build error :
 Can't resolve '../assets/images/logo.png'

Comment: @rahultiwari what if you keep baseHref='/' only in index.HTML file ?